# What is the scope of this object

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following code snippet which uses'event'
My fellow developers argue that the scope of 'var event' is restricted to 'if' condition.
Is that true. How can I make this a better code

```
function prepForDrag(obj, event) {      
    if(event= "undefined"){  
        var event=obj || window.event;
    }
    if (event.altKey) {
        showShiftEditable(objCurrentEditRow, nCurrentEditableShift, lCurrentEditableBreak, true);    
        var thisForm = eval('document.${formName}');
        // ...
        enableDragState(obj);
        disableClickEditHandler(obj);  ## remove 'normal' line sched click handling in dd mode
    }
  }
```

Comment: This post will be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684923/javascript-variables-declare-outside-or-inside-loop/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not true. In JavaScript there is **no block scope, only function scope**<sup>*</sup>. All variables introduced in a function are hoisted up to the top of the function.

So this code:

```
function prepForDrag(obj, event) {
    if (event = "undefined") {
        var event = obj || window.event;
    }
    // ...
}
```

gets interpreted somewhat like this:

```
function prepForDrag(obj, event) {
    if (event = "undefined") {
        event = obj || window.event;
    }
    // ...
}
```

As [Marcel Korpel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258127/marcel-korpel)'s pointed out, declaring variable `event` is unnecessary in this case because `event` is already a local variable since it's a function parameter. For futher details, read Ben Cherry's article on [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting).

Nevertheless there are two additional problems in your code.

1. In the condition you used the `=` assignment operator instead of the `==` comparision operator. So the condition always evaluates to true.
2. If you want to check whether a function argument was given, use the `typeof event == 'undefined'` statement.

And I'm afraid there is even one more issue here. What is the purpose of the condition? Does argument `obj` anything to do with `event`? Modern browsers pass an event object to the event handler function as argument but [some do not](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html). To avoid the problem, the following pattern tends to be used:

```
function prepForDrag(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    // ...
}
```

<sup>*</sup>NB: there is a [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) introduced in JavaScript 1.7 that provides block scope inside functions. Currently [it's only supported in Firefox](http://www.robertnyman.com/javascript/#javascript-1-7-compatibility).

Comment: This is still not completely correct: as `event` is already a parameter to `prepForDrag`, it already has the local scope and declaring the variable using `var` not necessary. You last example of normalizing the Event interface is incorrect: the Event interface is passed as the *first* argument to an event handler, so in this case `obj` would hold the Event interface, `e` never does.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: you're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing them out.

Answer (score 6):

As `event` is already a parameter to `prepForDrag`, its scope is **local to the function**.

But your `if` condition is wrong:

```
if(event= "undefined")
```

This assigns `"undefined"` to `event` and evaluates to `true`. You probably should use

```
if (typeof event == "undefined")
```

or (as I think what you want is)

```
function prepForDrag(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.altKey) {
      showShiftEditable(objCurrentEditRow, nCurrentEditableShift, lCurrentEditableBreak, true);    
      var thisForm = eval('document.${formName}');
      ................................
      enableDragState(obj);
      disableClickEditHandler(obj);  // remove 'normal' line sched click handling in dd mode
    }
}
```

BTW, why are you `eval`ing `document.${formName}`?

Comment: @Korpel : This is very old (5yrs) code.never touched/remodelled unless faced issues. This one is FF compatability issue. So eval ing is basically reading form data which of course poor javsripting :-(

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have block scope (except the exception variable inside a `catch` block), so in your case, that `event` variable has function scope. The best you can do, is to reassign `event` with the new value, or maybe use another variable name.