# Is there anything wrong with declaring your vars inside of a for loop or an if block?

Tags: javascript, variables

I often see the habit:

```
var foo, bar;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    foo = '' + foo + i;
}
```

It's also rubbed off onto me, but I've just realized I have no idea why I do it.

Comment: Nothing wrong as long as you realize that there's no block scope, only function scope.

Comment: What's wrong with it is that the code implies that the variable is declared at that statement, which is not true. Variable names are bound at the beginning of the function call, *before* any of the statements of the function body are executed. In order to comply with that behavior, it is recommended that variable declaration statements appear only at the beginning of the function code, before any other types of statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript variables declare outside or inside loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684923/javascript-variables-declare-outside-or-inside-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real problem with doing it, however javascript does not have block level scope, so if you declare foo inside the loop it's still accessible throughout the whole function.

There is a small advantage when doing minification if you declare all your variables up front, consider:

```
// Up front
var a, b, c, aVal, bVal, cVal;

for (a = 0; a < 5; ++a) {
    aVal = a;
}

for (b = 0; b < 5; ++b) {
    bVal = b;
}

for (c = 0; c < 5; ++c) {
    cVal = c;
}

// Inline
for (var a = 0; a < 5; ++a) {
    var aVal = a;
}

for (var b = 0; b < 5; ++b) {
    var bVal = b;
}

for (var c = 0; c < 5; ++c) {
    var cVal = c;
}
```

In this case, when you minify there will be a lot more "var" statements appearing in your source. It's not a huge deal, but they can certainly add up over time.

Comment: Depends on the minifier. A *good* minifier would treat both code semantically equivalent. But +1 for "There is no [..] problem with doing it .."