# JQuery getting an array of elements and changing their CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is super weird... I'm trying to make a validation function for some forms but I can't seem to run any JQuery on the elements in the array JQuery gives me.

This breaks when it hits the .css line. I have similar problems on the .val() and the sceond .css. Whaaaaat?

```
function isRequiredFilled(prepend){
    var reqs = $(prepend + ' .required');
    var filled = true;
    for(var i=0; i<reqs.length; i++){
        reqs[i].css("background-color", "white");
        if(!reqs[i].val()){
            reqs[i].css("background-color", "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7f");
            filled = false;
        }
    }
    return filled;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your code doesn't work as already been explained in the other answers. Here is a more jQuery-ish solution:

```
function isRequiredFilled(prepend){
    var reqs = $(prepend + ' .required').css("background-color", "white");
    var empty_reqs = reqs.filter(function() {
        return !this.value;
    }).css("background-color", "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7)");

    return empty_reqs.length === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery object is an array-like object. Inside the array are the native DOM elements.
Try wrapping each iterated value inside another jQuery selector to have access to the jQuery methods, like so:

```
function isRequiredFilled(prepend){
    var reqs = $(prepend + ' .required');
    var filled = true;
    for(var i=0; i<reqs.length; i++){
        var $req = $(reqs[i]);
         $req.css("background-color", "white");
        if(! $req.val()){
             $req.css("background-color", "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7f");
            filled = false;
        }
    }
    return filled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when doing `reqs[i]`, you get the DOM element, not the jQuery object. You don't have access to jQuery method. Use `.eq()` :

```
reqs.eq(i).val();
reqs.eq(i).css();
//Etc.
```

- [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Caching the element would be a good idea aswell :

```
var $myEl = reqs.eq(i);
```

Use something like this :

```
function isRequiredFilled(prepend){
    var reqs = $(prepend + ' .required');
    var filled = true;
    for(var i=0; i<reqs.length; i++){
        var $currentReq = reqs.eq(i)
        $currentReq.css("background-color", "white");
        if(!$currentReq.val()){
            $currentReq.css("background-color", "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7f)");
            filled = false;
        }
    }
    return filled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `each`? https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
function isRequiredFilled(prepend){
  var reqs = $(prepend + ' .required');
  var filled = true;
  reqs.each(function (i, req) {
    req.css("background-color", "white");
    if (!req.val()){
        req.css("background-color", "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7f)");
        filled = false;
    }
  });
  return filled;
}
```

Also added a missing `)`.

Answer (score 0):

The above comments are correct -- `reqs[i]` will give you the DOM element, but since you want to call jQuery methods `val()` and `css()` on the element, what you really want is the *jQuery object* that *references* that DOM element.

Replace your function with the following:

```
function isRequiredFilled(prepend){

    // Added $ to variable name as per jQuery coding convention
    var $reqs = $(prepend + ' .required');

    var filled = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < reqs.length; i++) {

        // jQuery object that references your desired DOM node
        var $el = $reqs.eq(i); 

        // do stuff with the $el variable
        $el.css("background-color", "white");
        if (!$el.val()) {
            $el.css("background-color", "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7f");
            filled = false;
        }
    }
    return filled;
}
```

Comment: `var $el = {};` is unnecessary. Why not just `var $el;` or even just declare the variable in the loop `var $el = $reqs.eq(i);`?

Comment: Good questions. (1) <code>var $el = {};</code> guards against the possibility of calling a jQuery method on something that is not an object and therefore generating an exception. However, in this case, the <code>for</code> loop won't run if <code>$reqs.length() === 0</code>, so you're right that <code>var $el;</code> is sufficient. (2) I declare variables outside of loops because of some misremembered advice about performance, but as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684923/javascript-variables-declare-outside-or-inside-loop, it doesn't seem to matter! Updating the function now. Thanks!

Comment: Assigning an empty object wouldn't help much though. E.g. if `$el.css()` is called, and `$el.css` is `undefined` (which it would be since `$el` is an empty object), then it would still throw an error, since `undefined` is not a function.