# JS toLowerCase() not working

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```js
//make first letter of each word capital
function titleCase(str) {
    /*
     *  1. change all letters to lower case
     *  2. split words
     *  3. set each 1st letter to Capital
     *  4. combine array back into string
     */
    arr = [];
    str.toLowerCase();

    arr = str.split(" ");

    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        arr[index].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    }

    str= arr.join(" ");
    return str;
}
console.log(titleCase("Potato potato potato"));
```

And I don't understand why `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` are not working. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What you are trying to do in `str.toLowerCase();` ?

Comment: `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` does not affect the value of the string `str` itself. You need to assign back the value to `str` after converting to lower case or upper case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Title case a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495239/title-case-a-sentence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 updates required

1. Reassign `str.toLowerCase()` to `str`
2. Reassign updated `array value` back in array.

Please note, until and unless you reassign the values, the original value does not change. Hence, the result remained unaffected.

```js
//make first letter of each word capital
function titleCase(str) {
/*
1. change all letters to lower case
2. split words
3. set each 1st letter to Capital
4. combine array back into string
*/
    arr = [];
    str = str.toLowerCase(); // **** Problem 1 - Reassigning

    arr = str.split(" ");

    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
       // **** Problem 2 - Reassigning
       arr[index] = arr[index].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[index].slice(1);
    }

    str= arr.join(" ");
    return str;
}
console.log(titleCase("Potato potato potato"));
```

Comment: the solution is so much overcomplecated.

Comment: @Durga - Agreed & Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaK - Correct, however, this brings the solution with minimal change in original code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign (overwrite) the value inside the array after you change it. Otherwise, the array remains unchanged. Besides, you forgot to add the rest of the string (arr[index].slice(1)) to the uppercased letter.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
    let arr = [];
    str.toLowerCase();

    arr = str.split(" ");

    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        arr[index] = arr[index].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[index].slice(1); // <-- Changes
    }

    str= arr.join(" ");
    return str;
}
console.log(titleCase("Potato potato potato"));
```

**EDIT**

Here is my own ES6 one-liner version :

```js
titleCase = str => str.trim().split(" ").map( word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) ).join(" ")
    
console.log(titleCase("Potato potato potato"));
```

Explanation :

```
titleCase = str => str
                   .trim() // Removes extra spaces
                   .split(" ")
                   .map( word =>
                        word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) // Uppercases 1st letter, adds the rest of the word, returns the whole
                   )
                   .join(" ") // Reforms a string
```

Comment: Just a pointer. Do not rush into posting an answer. An answer is incomplete without explanation. This attracts unwanted votes/comments like this. Its a good practice to incrementally update answer, but make sure your 1st cut justifies the term answer

Comment: you forgot to lowercase the rest of the words in your one liner solution. Again: Don't rush. Think about your solution and post it when you are ready.

Answer (score 0):

short solution:

```
var titleCase = (str)=>str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(word=>word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+word.slice(1)).join(' ');
```

calling:

```
titleCase('Potato potato potato');
```

Splitting the string by space and map a lambda to the resulting array. The lambda turns up the first letter and append the rest of the word.

---

as pointed out in the comments:

```
var titleCase = (str)=>str.toLowerCase().split(' ').reduce((currentString, word)=>currentString+(currentString ? ' ':'')+word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+word.slice(1));
```

this works also and loops only one time.

Comment: Reduce would suit more. `.map` + `.join` means you are looping twice

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do

```js
function convert(str){
    return str.split(' ').map(e => e.replace(/([A-Za-z])(\w+)/, (x, y, z) => y.toUpperCase()+z.toLowerCase())).join(' ');
}

console.log(convert('Potato potato pOtato'))
```