# Scope/Life of variable during for-iteration

Tags: javascript

```js
for (index1 = 1; index1 < 8; index1++) {
  var op = '#';
  for (index2 = index1; index2 - 1; index2--) {
    op = op + '#';

  }
  console.log(op);
}
```

In the above code and in the statement "var op = '#';", Is variable 'op' defined and initialized every time in 'for' iteration or defined once and initialized every time with the specific value..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is the same as the below snippet, because of [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). This means that `op` is declared once, but initialized to `#` every iteration of the outer loop.

```
var op;
for(index1 = 1 ;index1<8;index1++)
{
    op = '#'; 
    for (index2 = index1; index2-1; index2--) 
    {
        op = op + '#';

    }
    console.log(op);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your snippet which will log `#` in incrementing value for each iteration in your outer loop:

```js
for (index1 = 1; index1 < 8; index1++) {
  var op = '#';
  for (index2 = index1; index2 - 1; index2--) {
    op = op + '#';
  }
  console.log(op);
}
```

To explain why is that so, first, let's dissect your loops:

```
for (index1 = 1; index1 < 8; index1++) {
  var op = '#';
. . .
```

In this part, you created a variable `op` with a value `#`. For 7 iterations, it will be re-instantiated to the default value `#`.

But why is that the variable increments for each iteration? Let's move on to the inner loop:

```
for (index2 = index1; index2 - 1; index2--) {
    op = op + '#';
}
```

For each iteration inside this inner loop, you are appending an additional `#` to the default value of `op`.

Anyway, let's see how many iterations the inner loop is making for each iteration of the outer loop:

```js
var x = 0;

for (index1 = 1; index1 < 8; index1++) {
  //var op = '#';
  for (index2 = index1; index2 - 1; index2--) {
    //op = op + '#';
    x++;
  }
  console.log(x);
  x = 0;
  //console.log(op);
}
```

As you can see, it's making `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` iterations for each outer loop iteration. Meaning, on the first iteration, it doesn't append a `#`, adds 1 `#` on the second, and so on and so forth. So it justifies the results on your code.

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

**Side note:** Noticed something weird? Honestly, I find this loop very weird. But if I'm correct, it is because 0 is falsy and thus it wont execute the iteration, which is the second parameter in the loop. Please add a comment if my guess is right.

Anyway, I guess I have to post that as a question. I'll update this answer once I get responses from my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621855/weird-inner-loop-is-logging-more-iterations-than-the-outer-loop).

**EDIT:** Sorry, there were only 7 iterations for the `console.log(x)`. As for the weirdness of the loop condition, my guess is correct. `index2 - 1` can also be written as `index2 - 1 != 0` or more accurately `!!(index2 - 1)`. `!!` converts anything into Boolean. Any [falsey](https://j11y.io/javascript/truthy-falsey/) value will become false: `0`, `null`, `''`(*empty string*), `undefined`, `NaN`, and `false`.

As for your question *(darn, i almost forgot coz of the weird loop)*,  lets go back to the code:

```js
for (index1 = 1; index1 < 8; index1++) {
  var op = '#';
  for (index2 = index1; index2 - 1; index2--) {
    op = op + '#';
  }
  //console.log(op);
}
//let's see if the variable resides outside the outer loop

console.log(op);
```

**TADA!** It still logs `#######`. This is because of variable hoisting as what @Cristy said.

Comment: Outer for-loop is iterated from 1 to 7 and there comes 7 logs.Look again at the output..

Comment: oh weird.. i thought they were nine. i tried the code in the chrome debugger (*coz I lost briefly lost my internet connection*) and it logged 8 times

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variable will be function scope, because you are using `var`.

So the compiler / interpreter will move this variable to the beginning of the function through a process called hoisting.

If you want block scope, please use `let` instead of var.

In the case of your code `let` and `var` do not seem to make a difference in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The [`var` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is created at the top of the enclosing function, or since you're in the global scope, it's created as the script initializes in the global scope.

Within the outer loop, it's basically just an assignment of `#`, overwriting any previous value.

Within the inner loop, it appends another `#` to the value on each iteration.

If you used a [`let` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var`, then the variable would be scoped to the block of the outer loop, and inaccessible outside that block, though still accessible inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

*"Is variable 'op' defined and initialized every time in 'for' iteration or defined once and initialized every time with the specific value?"*

The `op` variable creates again on every parent loop iteration (`for (index1 = 1; index1 < 8; index1++) {...}`), but for every child `for` loop, it exists and you just override its value from child loop.

Answer (score 0):

"Is variable 'op' defined and initialized every time"

No.

"var" is a directive for the parser, and not a command executed at run-time. It makes no difference whether value is declared to be var inside the loop, outside the loop, or both.

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684923/javascript-variables-declare-outside-or-inside-loop)

I think it would be better for readability if the variable was declared outside of the loop.

This is a 
[scope](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)
question