# Weird inner loop not executing certain iterations

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was trying to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621252/scope-life-of-variable-during-for-iteration) where I encountered a weird loop condition.

```
for (index1 = 1; index1 < 8; index1++) {
  var op = '#';
  for (index2 = index1; index2 - 1; index2--) { //this loop is weird to me
    op = op + '#';
  }
  console.log(op);
}
```

Upon checking how many iterations the inner loop is making for each outer loop iteration I get this:

```js
var x = 0;

for (index1 = 1; index1 < 8; index1++) {
  //var op = '#';
  for (index2 = index1; index2 - 1; index2--) {
    var log = {};
    log.a = x; //check value before increment
    x++;
    log.b = x; //check value after increment
    console.log(`outer: ${index1}, inner: ${index2}`, log);
  }
  console.log(x);
  x = 0;
  //console.log(op);
}
```

As you can see, it logs `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

My questions is:

> Is the inner loop not iterating on the first outer loop iteration because  `index2 - 1` is equal to zero, which is falsy?

Comment: Try stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger.

Comment: `index2 - 1` is a bit awkward.

Comment: add `console.log` inside the inner loop, and log values

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, already did that. It seems it's not stepping inside the inner loop if `inde2 - 1 == 0`

Comment: In C-like languages (like JavaScript) "true" is anything non-zero, and "false" is zero. JavaScript adds a little more to that, but that's basically it, if you have zero, then it's false. Your condition could be rewritten as `index2 - 1 != 0`.

Comment: That's what I thought @Someprogrammerdude. Anyone want to post an answer? #2 question too please.

Comment: I don't see `7,0`. I only get `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

Comment: yeah.. sorry. i got confused with the additional 0 when i tried to run the code in the chrome debugger XD

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Right, on the first loop iteration `index1` == 1, `index1` is then assigned to `index2`, therefore `index2 - 1` == 0, which equates to false and your inner loop does not execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the inner loop not iterating on the first outer loop iteration because index2 - 1 is equal to zero, which is falsy?

That's correct. Any falsey value provided to the condition to the loop immediately halts the loop.

Falsey values are `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `""` and `false`.

Comment: There's your vote since you're the first to post an answer though @Someprogrammerdude should also be given the credit since he clarified my guess. As a comment though.